# Filter array of objects to a single matching object in mongodb/meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a query which looks as so:

```
var writer = Writers.findOne({
  _id: writerId,
  books: {
    $elemMatch: {
      id: Books.findOne({ slug: bookSlug })._id
    }
  }
});
```

However, this will return the full list of classes in the query.

```
{
  name: "H.P. Lovecraft",
  books: [{
    id: "1234",
    slug: "at-the-mountains-of-madness"
  }, {
    id: "5678",
    slug: "herbert-west-reanimator"
  }]
}
```

Would there be a way to eliminate all information except for the one item in the list I want and make it into an object? That is to say, I want my final result to be:

```
{
  name: "H.P Lovecraft",
  book: {
    id: "1234",
    slug: "herbert-west-reanimator"
  }
}
```

How would this be done in Meteor with mongodb?

Comment: you should be able to do that with a transform, given as a parameters to the `findOne`

Answer (score 2):

One approach you could take is to use the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#elemmatch-projection) projection operator with the findOne() query. For the document with `_id` equal to `writerId`, the [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#elemmatch-projection) projection returns only the first matching element from the array:

```
var bookId = Books.findOne({ slug: bookSlug })._id,
    writer = Writers.findOne({ _id: writerId },
                             { books: { $elemMatch: { id: bookId } }, 
                               _id: 0,
                               name: 1
                             }
    );
```

Another approach would be to use [**Underscore library's**](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/underscore) [**`_.find()`**](http://underscorejs.org/#find) method to return the specific array element:

```
var bookId = Books.findOne({ slug: bookSlug })._id,
    writer = Writers.findOne({
        _id: writerId,
        books: {
            $elemMatch: {
                id: bookId
            }
        }
    }),
    book = _.find(writer.books, function(book) {return book.id === bookId});
```

Comment: seems to work, but it's always an array in the projection. Is there a way to just make it an object?

Comment: Do you mean on the second approach?

Comment: nah, on the first, I think you can use `findWhere` for the second approach, no?

Comment: sorry, found the answer, worked on normal mongo, but on meteor, had to [wrap it in a field object](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/747)

Comment: @corvid No worries :-) glad you found something that solved your issue.